# mPDF only printing on Mac, giving Format error: not a pdf or corrupted on windows

Tags: php, mysqli, mpdf

I developed a PHP system using a MAC, so this system needs to print a PDF, so I used mPDF. The system is working PERFECTLY on MAC, but on Windows its giving me the "Format error: not a pdf or corrupted on windows" on every PDF it produces.

So I did the following:

- Deleted everything file/folder that is installed with `composer require mpdf/mpdf` and reinstalled mpdf using Composer, on the Windows computer(I thought it was a platform issue)
- Followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322746/convert-html-page-into-pdf-using-php/41324069#41324069) , to change the permissions, and changed the permissions of the entire vendor folder to 775
- tried entering the html text bit by bit to find out where the problem is, but the page is too big for that(besides the system is printing from different pages- all giving the same error.)
- the default text is working fine, the following:

  ```
  <?php
  $path = __DIR__;
  require_once $path . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $html = "Hello World";

  try {
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
      'margin_left' => 20,
      'margin_right' => 15,
      'margin_top' => 68, //48
      'margin_bottom' => 25,
      'margin_header' => 30, //10
      'margin_footer' => 10
  ]);

  $mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
  $mpdf->SetTitle("Report");
  $mpdf->SetAuthor("Vincent H Guyo.");
  $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage("logo.jpg");
  $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
  $mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
  $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
  $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  $mpdf->Output();
  } catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) { // Note: safer fully qualified exception name used for catch
  // Process the exception, log, print etc.
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  ?>
  ```

So on this works fine, the moment I try to change the $html variable to what i want, thats when the problem comes.

Any help or directions are very much welcome and needed. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your input then? Also, can you open the PDF as a text and see if there are no error messages at the beginning of the file? See https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/corrupt-pdf-file.html

Comment: I followed the troubleshooting guide you provided, enabled debug mode,

Comment: I followed the troubleshooting guide you provided, enabled debug mode, got 

Output has already been sent from the script - PDF file generation aborted.

then I used, ob_end_clean(); as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13291444/4481886 

Now its working.